# Resolving a question that has answers that don't cover the entire question

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

[This is the question that I am referring to if needed.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13430651/differentiating-between-portrait-mode-on-handheld-devices-and-desktops)

I asked a question regarding media queries and the detection of mobile devices. The answers that were relevant focused on the detection of devices and orientation using JavaScript, but failed to tie it together with the media queries and LESS CSS implementation side of things.

The comments within the answers here were relevant to helping solve the problem, but not fully (vanilla CSS, not nested LESS), and additionally were not posted by the original answerer. I have since solved the LESS issue, and thus the entire problem.

1. Should I accept the closest answer / the one that helped me the most and leave it at that? (this has already been awarded a bounty)
2. Should I write and accept my own answer that compiles it all?
3. Should I alter the question with a compiled solution and accept the closest answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally would accept the closest/most helpful answer, and then leave a comment on it.  Sometimes if the posted answer wasn't actually how I solved the problem, I've accepted my own answers.

Also, in the future, try as best you can to ask only one question per question, so you don't have to deal with this as  much

Answer (score 1):

Either #1 or #2 would be appropriate; as to which, it depends context and on your preferences.

Mostly it's a matter of how much information was needed to solve the problem that isn't included in the answer.  If it's just a little bit, and the answer really does have most of what's needed (and the particularly hard/tricky parts) then I'd accept it.  Consider commenting on the answer to add the little bit of missing info.  (If the mssing info fits into a comment it's a good indication the answer is close enough.)

If it helped a bit, but not all that much, then consider just upvoting but providing your own answer and accepting it, particularly if you have enough information that you need a new answer just to list it all.

There tends to be some level of personal preference as to where to draw that line between somewhat helpful and an only slightly incomplete answer.  In the end it's up to you, the asker, to decided what you want to mark as the accepted answer.

You should *not* edit the answer into the question, that's an inappropriate place for such information.

Comment: It would involve a code block of how to access that information in the context of nested LESS. If you were simply coding in CSS the answer and resulting comments would be fine...